# .NET Webbrowser Control Capture Downloads

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, webbrowser-control

How can I capture the downloaded files that Webbrowser automatically downloads (such as .html, png, etc.)

For example, if a website downloads a html file every 30 seconds via javascript, how can I capture this html using web browser control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach will be

**Step 1 Grab the content of the script element (the variable which have html file path)**

```
//using HtmlAgilityPack
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
//Considering first script tag (you need to check your decentands)
var script = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                             .Where(n => n.Name == "script")
                             .First().InnerText; 

// Return the data of the spect and stringify it into a proper JSON object
var engine = new Jurassic.ScriptEngine();
var result = engine.Evaluate("(function() { " + script + " return spects; })()");
var json = JSONObject.Stringify(engine, result);

Console.WriteLine(json);
Console.ReadKey();
```

**Step 2: Open the html page in another web browser control or same browser control**

```
WebBrowser wb2 = new WebBrowser();
wb2.AllowNavigation = true;
wb2.Navigate(jsVariableAsString);
```

**Step 3: Save the page of web browser**

```
var html = wb2.DocumentText.ToString();
```

or wb2.ShowSaveAsDialog();

Let me know if it works.